# The upcoming data not proper show in aura lightning Data Table?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura-attribute

I write any object query and not mention ID filed but in table the id field show automatically so I am not getting what exact problem behind that and when I don't enter the object name then the object related account is getting so it should happen that when I enter the object name and the object related query then the data should appear.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

**Design** Code:-

```html
<design:component>
    <design:attribute name="objectName" Label="Object Name"/>
    <design:attribute name="Query" Label="Query"/>
</design:component>
```

**Component** Code:-

```html
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" controller="DesignAttClass" >

    <aura:attribute name="objectName" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="Query" type="String" />
    <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.doInit}" value="{!this}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="recordsData" type="List"/>
    <aura:attribute name="recordTableColList" type="List" />
    
    <lightning:card>
        <!--Lightning Data Table Start-->
        <lightning:datatable
             keyField="id"
             data="{! v.recordsData }"
             columns="{! v.recordTableColList }"
             hideCheckboxColumn="false"      
             onrowselection ="{!c.selectedLeadRows}"
             />
        <!--Lightning Data Table End-->
    </lightning:card>
    
</aura:component>
```

**JS** Helper Code:-

```js
({
    getRecrdHelper : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get('c.getRecords');
        action.setParams({'query' : component.get('v.Query'), "objectName" : component.get('v.objectName')});
        action.setCallback(this, function (res){
            if(res.getState() === 'SUCCESS'){
                console.log('Received = '+JSON.stringify(res.getReturnValue()));
                let dynamiccolumns = [];
                for (let key in res.getReturnValue()[0]) {
                    dynamiccolumns.push({
                        fieldName: key,
                        label: key,
                        type: "text"
                    });
                }
                component.set('v.recordTableColList', dynamiccolumns);
                component.set('v.recordsData', res.getReturnValue());
            }else{
                console.log('Something went wrong...!!!!');
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

**Apex** Class Code:-

```java
public class DesignAttClass {
    
    @AuraEnabled 
    public static sObject[] getRecords(String query) {
            return Database.query(query);     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Id is always returned in a query from Apex. You will need to filter it out if you don't want to show it. Further, your code doesn't need the Object Name; you're already providing it a complete query. You would probably want to change your design to accept an object and list of fields in order to perform the query. You could even combine this logic with getObjectInfo to verify that the user has access to the object and fields specified before attempting to perform the query.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox Can you please tell me exactly what to do in this code as I am not getting any clarification from your answer ?